# Mozilla's Persona (BrowserID): Domain + Subdomain login

Tags: javascript, html, mozilla, browserid

Following problem.

I have a website:

- `example.com`

but there are some side websites lets say:

- `data.example.com`
- `help.example.com`

They are all run by the same flask application. 
Now I want the user be able to click login on any of those websites and be logged in on all of them.
Right now there are two post requests available at:

- `example.com/api/login`
- `example.com/api/logout`

Now the issue is, when logging in from example.com everything works beautifully. I am even logged in on the subdomains themselves. Thank you Mozilla. But when logging in from one of the other subdomains I get a failure response due to domain mismatch, which makes perfect sense to me since its a security risk.

I know of two solutions:

1. When on the subdomain redirect to the real domain first and have the user click login again.
2. Create `/api/login` and `/api/logout urls` for every subdomain itself. **Problem here is user needs to logout at the url he logged in**

Of course method 2 would be better for the user.

Now the real question is there any way to login from these subdomains without `login/logout` urls for each domain?

Let me know if I need to clarify. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be for `data.example.com` and `help.example.com` to have an iframe with the `example.com` login button in it, instead of these two subdomains hosting their own login buttons.

That way, when users go to the two subdomains, they end up clicking the login button for the top-level domain (`example.com`) and setting a cookie that will work on all three.

Comment: Thats a pretty good idea, haven't thought of that. Right now I am going with my method 2 although I don't like it a 100%. (I was able to get rid of the problem I had earlier with it) I will check out your idea tomorrow and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for exactly what is currently in [PR 3854](https://github.com/mozilla/browserid/pull/3854). There is also some discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.identity/z3d_wj6Jjq0/discussion). It looks like it should find its way into master very soon.